# Failed to lookup view, correct filename and location

Tags: node.js, express

I was following instructions from here: https://scotch.io/tutorials/easy-node-authentication-setup-and-local, when i got this error when trying to run my code,

`Error: Failed to lookup view "index.ejs" in views directory "Directory/views"`

```
at EventEmitter.render (Directory/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:579:17)
at ServerResponse.render (Directory/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:961:7)
at Directory/ourMeanJS/config/routes.js:10:13
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (Directory/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
at next (Directory/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:131:13)
at Route.dispatch (Directory/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:112:3)
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (Directory/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
at Directory/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:277:22
at Function.process_params (Directory/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:330:12)
at next (Directory/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:271:10)
at Directory/node_modules/connect-flash/lib/flash.js:21:5
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (Directory/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
at trim_prefix (Directory/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:312:13)
at Directory/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:280:7
at Function.process_params (Directory/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:330:12)
at next (Directory/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:271:10)
```

here is my route setup:

```
module.exports = function(app, passport) {

// =====================================
// HOME PAGE (with login links) ========
// =====================================
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.render('index.ejs'); // load the index.ejs file
});
```

here is some of my server.js:

```
app.set('view engine', 'ejs'); // set up ejs for templating
require('./config/routes.js')(app, passport);
```

my views are in Directory/views and i have a view called index.ejs. anyone have a clue as to what is going wrong?

*edit just realized that this route works, don't know if it is a clue

```
app.get('/signup', function(req, res) {

    // render the page and pass in any flash data if it exists
    res.render('signup.ejs', { message: req.flash('signupMessage')});
});
```

Answer (score 5):

I also had this problem, my finder was showing the file as index.ejs but it actually was index.ejs.html behind the scenes. To fix this on mac right click on your file -> get info -> and remove the .html extension from it.

Answer (score 2):

Figured it out. index.ejs was actually index.ejs.html but was not displaying the .html in my gui.

Answer (score 0):

From the error "Error: Failed to lookup view "index.ejs" in views directory "Directory/views"

I can assume that you have set views directory properly.

Try this :

```
res.render('index');
```

Comment: tried that, got Error: Failed to lookup view "index" in views directory "Directory/views"

Comment: do u have index.ejs in directory/views ?

Comment: can you show me how u have defind view directory in express ?

Comment: Like this : app.set('views', __dirname + '/yourViewDirectory');

Comment: app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');

Comment: just added it, no difference

Comment: can you show me your project structure , your main file and ejs file location

Comment: directory:{
   server.js
   views:{
       index.ejs}
   config:{
        routes.js}}

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same err but from diff code project. 
I rem-out all the others kept the skeleton only, still the same.
So I decided to suspect if something inside of "index.ejs" has something, therefore, created a new file called "XX.ejs" and had my .js refer to it. From static HTML code to copied everything from index.ejs to it, worked beautifully! Calling it "XX.ejs" and "XX" not matter at all.
As soon as inside the .js I put it back to "index" or "index.ejs", wah-lah, got the original error.
Don't believe "index" or "index.ejs" are reserved words, and writer's source code is using it too and works.